# What is a platform independent way to access SBO?

Tags: php, sapb1

So, is there any direct way to do that (without using a proxy)?

Answer (score -1):

There should be some SOAP Web Services on the SAP side. If you find them, use the WSDL and call the services using [SoapClient](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php) in PHP.